# Dollar Sign In C# List.Add Function

Tags: c#

this might be a trivial question for the experienced programmers, however I came across this line of code and want to understand what it does.
please see the code below where we are adding the in the entries list and also incrementing the count as well.

```
 public class Journal
 {
    private readonly List<string> entries = new List<string>();

    private static int count = 0;

    public int AddEntry(string text)
    {
        entries.Add($"{++count}: {text}"); // my question is about this line of code
        return count;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

what is the purpose of doller sign in the mentioned line.

Comment: This is [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: this is string interpolation => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is used for string interpolation,

with it you can write something like:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Test, this is your message: {message}");
```

instead of using the older command and syntax:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Test, this is your message: {0}", message));
```

Comment: Sir, You hold a C# Hammer! Get on your desk, shout "Ragnarok", and close it as the dupe it is.

Comment: this is great, I didn't knew we can do operations within this function too.